# Periodically call of a Servlet from jsp page (Java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, servlets

I have a problem and i don't know how to resolve it...

I have 2 .dbf files with ~10000 records (geospatial informations) that i want to read from a jsp page, every time i read 200 records i have to send them to a servlet in some format (i haven't decided yet). 
The Servlet must save every record as a Document object in Google Appengine (the limit of 200 records is specified by Appengine api's).

I can't upload the file to server and read server-side cause of some AWT classes not supported by Appengine, then i tried to read the files client-side and send to server the parsed records but i don't know how i can do this.

Someone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: `jsp` once complied is nothing but a `servlet`. Why not do all your reading and saving in the `jsp` itself?

Answer (score 0):

`jsp`, once complied, is nothing but a `servlet`. That being said, you say:

*I can't upload the file to server and read server-side cause of some AWT classes not supported by Appengine*

Once you finish reading 200 records, why not insert it into the `appengine` from the `jsp` itself. The `jsp` will run on the server either way.

Comment: The problem is that i have to process these files client side after jsp page are processed by the server, probably the answer is not really correct sorry but is not so simple... probably i have to use some Javascript function and call a Servlet from this, but the classes to read these file are written in Java, in someway i have to insert java code into javascript contained in jsp page, and i don't know if it's possible...

Always used php and js, my knowledge about servlet and jsp is near 0...

Comment: What is this processing you want to do exactly?

Comment: Ok I explain all in detail.
I have a sample application on Google Appengine with a single web page in jsp. This page has 2 input file field and one button "import".
In theory when i click the button, the application should read the files, parse them (using a Java class) and send 200 parsed records at a time to a servlet.
This servlet create 200 Document objects with the informations received and insert data into Datastore.
This will continue until all record are inserted.

The problem is that the parser class don't run on Appengine then i have to use it client-side before sending all.